# Print only 5 items per row

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop

I currently have a list of items at hand.

For instance ,

```
List <string> listOfItem = new List <string>()
{
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3",
  "item4",
  "item5",
  "item6",
  "item7",
  "item8",
  "item9",
  "item10",
  "item11",
}
```

I am trying to do an Excel Export where I only print 5 first items , then I move to next sheet and print the next five items and the process repeats.

This what I've tried

```
int j = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < listOfItem.Count; i+=4)
{
    if (listOfItem[i] != null){
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Merge();
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]] = orderDate[i];
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Font.Size = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    if (listOfItem[i +1] != null){
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]].Merge();
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]] = listOfItem[i+1];
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]].Font.Size = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 3)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    if (listOfItem[i+2] != null){
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+3], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]].Merge();
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+4], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]] = listOfItem[i+2];
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+4], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+4], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+4], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]].Font.Size = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+4], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 5)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    if (listOfItem[i+3] != null){
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]].Merge();
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]] = listOfItem[i+3];
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]].Font.Size = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 7)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    if (listOfItem[i+4] != null){
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9)]].Merge();
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9)]] = listOfItem[i+4];
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j+ 8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9)]].Font.Size = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j + 8], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 9)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
}
```

I done the `if else` is because in case of the list having only.. example, 3 items, then the code will execute based on 3 items due to the `if else` loop.

However, this code is lengthy, is there a more refine/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
int j = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < listOfItem.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<((listOfItem.Count*2)-2);j+=2)
    {
        if (listOfItem[i] != null)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Merge();
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]] = listOfItem[i];
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Font.Size = "11";
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, (j + 1)]].Font.Name = "Arial";
        }
    }
}
```

This will go for one sheet you can also pull up more worksheet and wrap the code in a foreach loop to send data to another sheet accordingly.

Comment: Why does j loop goes up to `listOfItem.Count*2 -1` ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Yup!! it should be `-2` instead of `-1`

Comment: there's another point, if you see in original program, since OP is just printing 5 values and then shift to another sheet, so at a given point of time `j` is also restricted to 5 values and then need to reset, `(listOfItem.Count*2)-2` may not guarantee that